# Obtain timestamp of the last Front cache clear on Typoscript (Typo3 8+)?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I need to bind an script with the `nomodule` string

```
<script src="path/to/my/script.js" nomodule></script>
```

Since there are no way to do this directly on `includeJS` I have to do it on `footerData` but I need to append the cache string. Is there a way to get it on Typoscript?

Comment: Do you want to append file modification time in URL?

Comment: I want to append the `nomodule` attribute.